# Is it better to perform sort logic for List through orderby in the database, or is it better to use Collection.sort() in Java logic?

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

When you want to sort and return some data, which logic should you use for sorting?

When receiving any kind of data as a list, is it better to receive the sorted data through Order by on the DB side and use it as it is? Or is it better to not use orderby on the DB side, receive data as it is, and then sort on the spring side?

For reference, spring-boot, jpa, QueryDSL are used, and DB is mysql.

*I would appreciate it if you could tell me a better way and why!!!*

Comment: I would recommend you to check similar question at 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/250823/89507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you can do it in SQL, do it in SQL.

Database engines are really impressive in executing SQL fast an efficient.

Only if the number of rows is rather limited and the order by is extremely complex to do in SQL, would I consider doing it in the JVM

Answer (score 1):

This answer is supplementary to @Jens Schauder's answer. A good architecture will separate data access from business logic and whatever goes beyond (web layer etc.).

Make sure that data structures that preserve ordering are used when you collect data from the database abstraction layer. Also make sure that as the data make its way through the application, this ordering is preserved.

I've seen scenarios where the data access layer orders data, then an engineer uses an unordered collection down the line, E.G. a `Set`, rather than a `List`.

Good unit testing will see you right.